# Linq Loop Compare Values ListBox ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to condense my code by avoiding multiple foreach loops to accomplish this task.  I have a listbox that is populated by Table A.  I need to compare those values with Table B to populate another list.

Table A has a 1 to many relationship with Table B and while my solution worked for the time being, it is using quite a bit of memory so I need to condense it.

```
List<int> listProj = new List<int>();

var _tableB = from t in TableB
              where t.StatID == 1 || t.StatID == 2
              select p.ID;

var _tableA = from ListItem n in lstTableA.Items
              where _tableB.Contains(int.Parse(n.Value)) && n.Selected == true
              select n;

foreach (ListItem i in _tableA)
{
    int affID = Convert.ToInt32(i.Value);
    if (TableB.Where(t => t.ID == affID && t.StatID == 1 || t.StatID == 2).Any()
    {
        foreach(var item in TableB.Where(t => t.ID == affID && t.StatID == 1 || t.StatID == 2)
        {
            int pID = Convert.ToInt32(item.pID);
            listProject.Add(projID);
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that these two loops are looping through quite a bit of records which is causing a memory leak.  I feel that there is a way to grab many records at once and add them to the list, hence the one to many relationship between Table A and Table B.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would give you the same result as the whole code above unless I'm making a mistake on the logic of your program.

This would return the project ids:

```
List<int> listProj = (from t in TableB
                        where (from n in lstTableA.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToList()
                            where n.Selected == true
                            select n).Any(g => int.Parse(g.Value) == t.ID)
                            && (t.StatID == 1 || t.StatID == 2)
                        select t.pID).ToList();
```

Comment: That was my mistake.  Yes that is close but within the final foreach loop I'm grabbing an unshared value.  pID is only an attribute of Table B and that's what I need to make a list of.  I've edited above to conform.

Comment: That seems like it would work to me but I get the error:
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'.  Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Did it work for you?

Comment: I appreciate it.  I was unable to do a direct ".ToList()" so I did a "lstTableA.Items.Cast<string>().ToList()" but received another error of "...this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I think it has to do with mixing linq to objects and linq to entities...

Comment: Tried the latest update but got the same error as the second comment down.  "...Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid')..."

Comment: I think the condition of method .Any() is incorrect, it should be g.Value rather than g.ID, also add the ToList() at the end

Comment: That brings it back to the "...cannot be translated into a store expression." error.  Appreciate the help though.